# Strategy Pattern: How to make classes with constructors as enums?

Tags: java, enums, strategy-pattern

I'm creating a Strategy pattern in Java.

This is my Strategy Interface **ActivationStrategy.java**:

```
public interface Strategy {
    public void strategyAlgo(JTextField textField);
}
```

I have different classes which implement the Interface. Those classes have a constructor because it's necessary to passing values. For example:

**FirstStrategy.java**

```
public class FirstStrategy implements Strategy{
    private JComboBox<String> _comboBox;

    public FirstStrategy(JComboBox<String> comboBox) {
        _comboBox = comboBox;
    }

    public void strategyAlgo(JTextField textField) {
        textField.addKeyListener(new myKeyHandler(_comboBox, textField));
    }
```

**SecondStrategy.java**

```
public class SecondStrategy implements Strategy{
    private JPanel _panel;

    public secondStrategy(JPanel panel) {
        _panel = panel;
    }

    public void strategyAlgo(JTextField textField) {
        addActionHandlerToButton(addButton(_panel));
    }

    public JButton addButton(JPanel panel) {
        JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
        panel.add(button);
        return button;
    }

    public void addActionHandlerToButton(JButton okButton) {
        Action action = new AbstractAction(){    
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Hi");           
            }
        };
        button.addActionListener(action);           
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to make the classes as enums.
Something like:

```
public enum strategies {

    FIRSTSTRATEGIE(){
      @Override
        public void strategyAlgo() {
        ...
        }
    },
    SECONDSTRATEGY(){
      @Override
        public void strategyAlgo() {
        ...
        }
        public JButton addButton(JPanel panel) {
        ...
        }
        public void addActionHandlerToButton(JButton okButton) {
        ...
        }
    };

    public abstract void strategyAlgo();

}
```

But what about the constructors?

Comment: Do you need a field in you classes? Can't you pass the panel/combobox directly to the strategyAlgo method?

Comment: But not all Strategies need a Panel or a ComboBox.

Comment: I assume if you want to make them enums then your current strategy objects are singletons already. Is that right?

Comment: I don't think that's suitable for your needs. You pass a certain instance of ComboBox to your first strategy and a specific instance of JPanel to your second one. When you use enums, each strategy will only exist once, not once per ComboBox/JPanel instance. This would only make sense if your current strategies are singletons.

Comment: Know that the specific methods inside the enum constants will not be accessible, only `strategyAlgo`. Why do you want to do this? There might be other solutions.

Comment: I think you might be better off creating an `EnumMap` from plain constants to instances of your strategies, instead of trying to use the enums themselves as the strategies.

Answer (score 1):

My criteria when `enum`s are a viable choice?

1. When the number of instances are determined at compile time.
2. When the state of each instance is determined at compile time.
3. When your instances do not hold mutable state.

In your case criterion `2.` is not `true`. Hence in my opinion you should not model your strategies as `enum`s.

Comment: I mend *Java* `enum` but `enum` is just an abbriviation for *Enumeration*. I think my text formatting was off.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an arbitrary instance of an enum at runtime. Therefore, you cannot pass anything to an enum's constructor that is not known at compile time.
You can pass dynamic arguments by changing list of arguments in your abstract method.

You can create a constructor in an Enum but it can be `private` only, so you cannot use it to create an arbitrary instance at runtime.
This way it is guaranteed that there is only one instance of a particular enum value.

For example:

```
public enum Suit {
  SPADES("spades"),
  HEARTS("hearts"),
  CLUBS("clubs"),
  DIAMONDS("diamonds");

  private String label;

  private Suit(String label) {
    this.label = label;
  }

}
```

BTW, `private` keyword is optional for a constructor in case of an `enum`. It's `private` by default.

Comment: But you cannot pass external values or references into it. Only constant values that are already known during the intialization of the enum. That's not helping in OP's case.